# Matplotlib: How can I show only exponents in the y tick labels of a semi-log plot with secondary_yaxis()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've been working on matplotlib's secondary-yaxis and I can't figure out how I should set "functions" parameter in order to get the result that I want.

I want to make a semi-log plot and set set the labels of y-ticks in the 2 following formats:

1. ordinary format such as "10^1, 10^2, 10^3, ..., 10^(exponent), ..."
2. the exponents only: "1, 2, 3, ..."

And I want to put them in the former style in the y-axis of left side, and the latter right side.

What I want to do can be done by using twinx() like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1, 3, 41)
y = 10**x

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax1.plot(x, y)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ymin, ymax = ax1.get_ylim()
ax2.set_ylim(np.log10(ymin), np.log10(ymax))

plt.show()
```

[image]

You would see that i=(1, 2, 3) in the right label is located at the same height as 10^i in the left label.

However, I want to know how to do the same thing by secondary_yaxis. I've tried this but it didn't work.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1, 3, 41)
y = 10**x

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.plot(x, y)

def forward(x):
    return np.log10(x)
def backward(x):
    return 10**x

secax = ax.secondary_yaxis('right', functions=(forward, backward))

plt.show()
```

It resulted in this:
[image]

You can see right-side tick labels are broken. I suspect that my way of setting the parameter "functions" of secondary_yaxis() might be invalid. I would appreciate it if you tell me how to do it.

Comment: It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhHaR.png) on matplotlib 3.3.0.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh Thank you, this looks almost the same as what I want. Where can I see the source code of this figure? If you made it, would you show the code as an answer for this question?

Comment: The code is the second source block in your post. I run your code on matplotlib 3.3.0 and it produces the image I posted before.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh My matplotlib was version 3.1.0. so I updated it to 3.3.0. Then I could get the same figure as your image. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I get the broken figure on matplotlib 3.1.0. and updating it to 3.3.0. has solved the problem. The same code as the second code block of the question generates this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfBug.png)